# How to implement a RESTful resource for a state machine or finite automata

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, state-machine

I'm a Rails and REST newbie and I'm trying to figure how best to expose a resource that is backed by a domain object that has a state machine (in other words is a finite automata).

I've seen a number of gems for making a model class a state machine, such as aasm, transitions, workflow, but none of them document examples of how they are actually used in a resource oriented controller. They all seem to imply that state transitions are triggered by an "event" , which is really a method call. Some questions I have with what this implies are:

1. The update action (PUT method) is not appropriate because PUT is suppose to be idempotent. The only this would be possible is if the state was sent as part of the representation. This is inconsistet with an "event". Is this correct?
2. Since, events aren't idempotent, then the a POST must be used. But, to which resource? Is there a subresource for each possible event? Or, is there one (/updatestate) that takes as its representation the event to trigger and any parameters to the event?
3. Since the state of the resource is modified by an event triggered potentially by another resource, should the create action accept changes to the state attribute (or any other attributes that are dependent on the state machine)?
4. [Updated question] What is a good way to expose the transitions in the UI? Since events aren't states, it would seem that it doesn't make sense to allow the state attribute (and any other attribute that is dependent on state transitions) to be updated. Does that mean that these attributes should be ignored in the update action?

Comment: My advice: don't drive yourself crazy trying to satisfy REST trolls with 100% so-called RESTfulness.  REST is a convenient tool for framing an API, but most complex APIs are forced to break REST, particularly PUT idempotence.

Comment: @dorkitude: There are many levels of RESTfulness it seems, but at the very least adhere to the basic rules: GET/PUT/DELETE for idempotent, POST for non-idempotent, HTTP error codes for failures, pointers to subresources described by parent resources. Those are the (relatively) easy parts too.

Comment: REST troll here: If you do not follow the REST constraints do not call it RESTfull but RESTlike ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> - The update action (PUT method) is not appropriate because PUT is suppose to be idempotent. The only this would be possible is if the state was sent as part of the representation. This is inconsistet with an "event". Is this correct?

Correct.

> - Since, events aren't idempotent, then the a POST must be used. But, to which resource? Is there a subresource for each possible event? Or, is there one (/updatestate) that takes as its representation the event to trigger and any parameters to the event?

You can do it both ways. You can support both in the same application, with variation in event types being determined by either the incoming document or the receiving resource. Personally, I would prefer to do it by differing document types, but that's just my opinion. If you *do* go the multiple resources route, make sure they're discoverable (i.e., by having links to each of them described in the document returned when you GET their parent resource).

> - Since the state of the resource is modified by an event triggered potentially by another resource, should the create action accept changes to the state attribute (or any other attributes that are dependent on the state machine)?

Up to you; there's no real reason why you have to pay close attention to any particular attribute on creation. (You could rationalize this by saying that the state changes to a proper initial state for the state machine immediately after creation.) In the state machines I've done, the creation was by a POST anyway (and of a different – rather complex – document) so the whole thing was moot, but if you allow multiple initial states then it makes sense to take a “this is my preferred starting state” hint in the creation document. To be clear, just because the user wants it doesn't mean you have to do it; whether you want to complain to the user when you reject a suggestion of theirs is your call.

> - List item

[Stock answer.]

Comment: @Galex: No real opinion about how to map to your GUI, to be honest. However, if you make setting the state to itself into something that is always a do-nothing action, you've got idempotency and can use PUT. You might not choose to do that because of the other things that happens, but it would fit well enough.

Comment: Been struggling with a similar issue. Your answer was very useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

A little late to the party here, but I was researching this exact issue for myself and found that the gem I'm currently using to manage my state machines ([state_machine by pluginaweek](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/)) has some methods that deal with this issue quite nicely.

When used with ActiveRecord (and I'm assuming other persistence layers as well), it provides a `#state_event=` method that accepts a string representation of the event you would like to fire. See documentation [here](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/blob/master/lib/state_machine/integrations/active_record.rb#L50).

```
# For example,

vehicle = Vehicle.create          # => #<Vehicle id: 1, name: nil, state: "parked">
vehicle.state_event               # => nil
vehicle.state_event = 'invalid'
vehicle.valid?                    # => false
vehicle.errors.full_messages      # => ["State event is invalid"]

vehicle.state_event = 'ignite'
vehicle.valid?                    # => true
vehicle.save                      # => true
vehicle.state                     # => "idling"
vehicle.state_event               # => nil

# Note that this can also be done on a mass-assignment basis:

vehicle = Vehicle.create(:state_event => 'ignite')  # => #<Vehicle id: 1, name: nil, state: "idling">
vehicle.state                                       # => "idling"
```

This allows you to simply add a `state_event` field in your resource's edit forms and get state transitions as easily as updating any other attribute.

Now we're obviously still using PUT to trigger events using this method, which isn't RESTful. The gem does, however, provide [an interesting example](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/tree/master/examples/rails-rest) that at least "feels" quite RESTful, despite it using the same non-RESTful method under the covers.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/blob/master/examples/rails-rest/view__form.html.erb#L22) and [here](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/blob/master/examples/rails-rest/view__form.html.erb#L27), the gem's introspection capabilities allow you to present in your forms either the event you would like to fire **or** the name of that event's resulting state.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :state %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :state_event, @user.state_transitions, :event, :human_to_name, :include_blank => @user.human_state_name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :access_state %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :access_state_event, @user.access_state_transitions, :event, :human_event, :include_blank => "don't change" %>
</div>
```

Using the latter technique, you get simple form-based updating of the model's state to any valid next state without having to write any extra code. It's not technically RESTful, but it allows you to easily present it that way in the UI.

The cleanliness of this technique combined with the inherent conflicts in trying to cast an event-based state machine into a simple RESTful resource was enough to satisfy me, so hopefully it provides some insight to you as well.

Comment: Very helpful answer. I somehow never came across the documentation for the `state_event` method. However, I may have encountered a limitation of this technique. You can't pass arguments to the transition event when you trigger it using the `state_event` method. That means that you can't record information like the `current_user` who triggered the event (like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6347369/574190).

Answer (score 7):

Bit late to the party here and far from an expert as I have a similar query but...

How about making the event a resource?

So instead of...

```
PUT /order/53?state_event="pay" #Order.update_attributes({state_event: "pay})
```

You would...

```
POST /order/53/pay     #OrderEvent.create(event_name: :pay)
POST /order/53/cancel  #OrderEvent.create(event_name: :cancel)
```

With a pub/sub listener between Order and OrderEvent or callback that attempts to fire that event on Order and records the transition messages. It also gives you a handy audit of all state change events.

Idea stolen from [Willem Bergen at Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/technology/5898287-restful-thinking-considered-harmful)

Am I missing something? Sorry, struggling to understand this myself.

Answer (score 3):

If your resource has some kind of status attribute, you can use a technique called micro-PUT to update it's status.

```
PUT /Customer/1/Status
Content-Type: text/plain

Closed

=> 200 OK
Content-Location: /Customer/1
```

You can model resource states as collections and move resources between those collections.

```
GET /Customer/1
=>
Content-Type: application/vnd.acme.customer+xml
200 OK


POST /ClosedCustomers
Content-Type: application/vnd.acme.customer+xml
=>
200 OK

POST /OpenCustomers
Content-Type: application/vnd.acme.customer+xml
=>
200 OK
```

You could always use the new PATCH method

```
PATCH /Customer/1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Status=Closed
=>
200 OK
```

Comment: Links to micro-PUT reference? Not something I've heard of before