# RESTful State Machine transition with Rails and Statesman Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, state-machine

This is a followup based on the great answers in [RESTful resource for a State Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591348/how-to-implement-a-restful-resource-for-a-state-machine-or-finite-automata) and this question is probably more rest related than State Machine

I am using the [Statesman Gem](https://github.com/gocardless/statesman) in a Rails 4.2 App. I have a Service model and an associated state_transitions model that stores the transitions through Active Record.

A transiton method is shown in the Statesman Docs as such:     `Order.first.state_machine.transition_to!(:cancelled)`

I know this is not even close

In my case I have `button_to 'ok', service_path, action: "#{service}.transition_to!(:received)"`

In my Service model transition_to is delegated to the state machine

How can I submit the request to change the state through my button_to form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you're confusing controller actions with actions on models.  They should really be two separate things - you should have a controller action that you can call from a view, and then inside that controller action, you can make your state change.  For example:

routes.rb

```
resources :orders do
  member do
    put "receive" => "orders#receive", as: :receive
  end
end
```

OrdersController

```
...
def receive
  order = Order.find(params[:id])
  if order.state_machine.transition_to!(:received)
    flash[:notice] = "Success"
    redirect_to action: :show, id: order.id
  else
    flash[:error] = "Could not transition to 'received'"
    render action: :show, id: order.id
  end
end
...
```

view.rb

```
...
= button_to "Mark as received", receive_order_path(order), method: :put
```

Note that I'm writing pseudo-code off of the top of my head, but it should be more or less valid.  Please excuse any minor syntax errors.

Comment: Great Answer and answered exactly what I was asking re: the difference between a controller action and an action on a model - or how do you connect up an http or RESful request and sending messages to and from objects - This answer really helps  Thanks